# belongsTo and hasMany not loading in the template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have these models:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  uid: DS.attr('number'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  fullName: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  homepage: DS.attr('string'),
  owner: DS.attr('string'),
  private: DS.attr('boolean'),
  organization: DS.belongsTo('organization', { async: true })
});
```

and

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  uid: DS.attr('number'),
  avatar: DS.attr('string'),
  blog: DS.attr('string'),
  company: DS.attr('string'),
  login: DS.attr('string'),
  location: DS.attr('string'),
  rooms: DS.hasMany('room', { async: true })
});
```

in the Ember Inspector I can see the whole data:

[image]

both rooms and organizations

when I try to show them in my template:

```
<div class="row">
    <ul id="room-list">
      {{#each model key="uid" as |room|}}
        <li>
          <label>{{room.uid}}: {{room.name}} ({{room.organization.name}}) </label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

the `()` where organization's name should be, is empty, like `53415342: PredictionIO-Enterprise ()`

Here is my serializer

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'uid'
});
```

and my server response on `/organizations/{uid}` is

```
{
  "uid": 1247016,
  "createdAt": 1470496909124,
  "name": "Tweek",
  "avatar": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1247016?v=3",
  "blog": "http://tweek.tv",
  "company": null,
  "login": "Ubertweek",
  "location": "Berlin, Germany",
  ....
```

Comment: Then the relationship is not correctly loaded. You can verify this in the ember-inspector when you click on a `room` record and in the right sidebar you click the $E on the `organization` property. Then look at the record dumped to the console, the `content` will be null. Your problem is in the server response and/or your serializer. May post more information about these parts.

Comment: you are right, the `content` is null...added more info